# How to build React-Native project with Xcode 12 Beta 4?

Tags: react-native, ios14, xcode12

When I try to build a project with Xcode 12 Beta 4 to test iOS14, I got a plenty of `Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64`. Every time I build the app, the list of errors is changed. Native libraries fail to recognize base React classes.

I opened a issue in React-Native repository: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/29633

A sample project with the error happening: https://github.com/igoriols/xcode12reactnativesample

Comment: One thing you need to do is update your command line tools. Xcode->preferences->locations-> install most recent version in drop down

Comment: Hi @steve-o. Thanks, but I already did that.

Answer (score 0):

Hey please check this here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/29633#issuecomment-694187116

the podspecs need an update.

Answer (score 0):

From one of the responses on [this issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/29633#issuecomment-705672827) I added a post install script with:

```sh
find ./node_modules -type f -name '*.podspec' | xargs sed -i.sed -e "s%'%\"%g"
find ./node_modules -type f -name '*.podspec' | xargs sed -i.sed -e 's%s.dependency[\t ]*"React"%s.dependency "React-Core"%g'
```

And everything builds perfectly.